# Capistrano RBENV path production error: failed: "env PATH=/home/user_with_rbenv/.rben

Tags: capistrano, rbenv

I have 2 SSH users. 1 which have rbenv installed.

I have watched the railscast about deploying to a VPS and some users have solved the problem with added the rbenv path.

```
set :default_environment, {
'PATH' => "/home/user_with_rbenv/.rbenv/shims:/home/user_with_rbenv/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
}
```

I am deploying from the user that does not have `.rbenv` included in its `/home/user` folder.

I get the following error:

```
   ←[2;37mcommand finished in 117ms←[0m
failed: "env PATH=/home/user_with_rbenv/.rbenv/shims:/home/user_with_rbenv/.rbenv/bin:$PATH sh -
c 'cd -- /var/www/user_with_rbenv/releases/20130215102746 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=
production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile && cp -- /var/www/app/share
d/assets/manifest.yml /var/www/app/releases/20130215102746/assets_manifest.y
```

`/home/user_with_rbenv/.rbenv` is the absolute path to the rbenv

And path is:

```
$ $PATH
-sh: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games: not found
```